# How to ensure a tooltip stays within the browser visible area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning how to create tooltips based on a [w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp).

One problem I am faced with is the visibility of the tooltips when the hovered-upon text is close to a browser edge and the tooltip is displayed outside of the visible area.

**Is there a standard way to prevent this (any approch (CSS, JS, ...) would be welcome)?**
The idea I have right now is to calculate the coordinates of the tooltip depending on the size of the screen and the position of the tooltip anchor - but I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel.

A tooltip which expands to the top or to the bottom would be enough - **maybe there is a "is completely visible" check which can be done to make a decision on the direction?** This would be similar to what is in place in tooltips in SO:

[image]

[image]

Comment: WoJ, guys here mostly hate W3Schools that maybe why you are downvoted !

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak Maybe, but they shouldn't downvote because of that... People should tell WoJ why they downvoted.

Comment: I think you are jumping to conclusions about the downvote being due to the W3Schools mention, it's more likely that it is because the question is a bit broad for SO. @WoJ, I suggest you add code showing what you have done it'll probably get a warmer reaction. That said, I can't think of a CSS only way of achieving this, your comment about calculating the position and size of the tooltip with JavaScript is how I have tackled this in the past.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes: As opposed to the vast majority of my questions where I provide code which can be hacked (= I am trying to give a complete, working example), here I wanted to get an early advice before jumping into convoluted code and realizing after the fact that there is a simple flag / approach for the problem I am having.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes How about no mercy in answers if w3schools is referenced instead of for example developer.mozilla

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the comments - I would be particularly grateful for an answer to the core question, though :)

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak Well unless the person who downvoted comments I guess we will never know the real reason, however, the question is a bit too broad at the moment so I'd like to give them the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to calculate if the position of the tooltip will be outside the window. In the example below I just add class `.bottom` to the `.tooltiptext` in this case.

The calculation is:

```
$('.tooltip').offset().top - $('.tooltiptext').height() < 0
```

In this case we should add that class.

The full example:

```js
$('.tooltip').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tooltip = $(this).find('.tooltiptext');
  var offset = $this.offset();

  tooltip.toggleClass('bottom', offset.top - tooltip.height() < 0);
  // - just for case you want to change the default behavior - tooltip.toggleClass('top', $(window).height() + tooltip.height() < 0);
});
```

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

    <style>
      .tooltip {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
      }

      .tooltip .tooltiptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 120px;
        background-color: #555;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -60px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 1s;
        bottom: 125%;
      }

      .tooltip .tooltiptext.bottom {
        bottom: auto;
        top: 125%;
      }

      .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
      }

      .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
      <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
    </div>

    <h2>Tooltip</h2>
    <p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
        <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://output.jsbin.com/nemebob

I let you to change the arrow direction to top.

Comment: That's just one of four cases where a simple tooltip could be off-screen.